# Laravel (blade) how to passe a Form into default @yield?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I've got a question: How you can pass a Form to default yield blade compenant ?

I try this:

```
@yield('nom_enfant', {{ Form::label('nom', 'Nom *', array('class' => 'label-form')) }} {{ Form::text('nom', null, array('class' => 'champ-form', 'required' => 'required')) }})
```

It doesn't work ... Anyone know how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally found it ....

the answer:

```
@yield('nom_enfant', Form::label('nom', 'Nom *', array('class' => 'label-form')) . Form::text('nom', null, array('class' => 'champ-form', 'required' => 'required')))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `@yield` directive is used to display the contents of a given section.

If you are to pass data to an extend view, then this should be done on the `@section` directive

Like so

`@section('foo', 'bar')`

You can then proceed to access the passed value as a php variable on the blade view like so

`<title>{{ $foo }}</title>`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in your blade file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
        <!--meta -->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
        <link rel="icon" type="icon/ico" href="{{URL::asset('resources/assets/images/favicon.ico')}}" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <!--main -->
     <div class="container-fluid">      
        <!--row -->
        <div class="row">
        <header>
        @include('layouts.header')
        </header>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show
        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
        <footer>
        @include('layouts.footer')
        </footer>
        </div>
        <!--row-->
     </div> 
     <!--main -->
    </body>
</html>
```